# Cannot resolve symbol - Scala

Tags: scala, selenium, intellij-idea

This code does not compile.

```
Actions anything = new Actions(getDriver)
```

I create the driver this way:

```
private var driverInstance: Option[_ <: RemoteWebDriver] = None

private def getDriver: RemoteWebDriver = driverInstance.getOrElse(reportDriverException)
```

The problem I get is that "anything" is underlined and it says

> Cannot resolve symbol anything

but when i change

```
Actions anything = new Actions(getDriver)
```

to

```
val anything = new Actions(getDriver)
```

it's seemingly fine - except that it's a val so obviously I can't do anything with it.

As it may be a problem with environment, I'm using Scala in IntelliJ IDEA 14 with Selenium 2.44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please clarify what do you mean by "except that it's a val so obviously I can't do anything with it"? What action do you want to take on `anything`? If you mean you cannot reassign its value, then you are right.
Whenever you need to reassign `anything` further just declare it as

```
var anything = new Actions(getDriver)
```

But you should prefer vals to vars by default.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. Yes, it works like that - but shouldn't it not be an error? It should compile Java seemlessly, right? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: No, Scala has it's own syntax. You can use Java types in Scala code seamlessly but not the Java syntax.